# Cardan Hobby Project - Concept question

Tags: nft, metadata

As hobby, I am trying to build a small website (using cardano db and nextjs) that would work as described :

- The website displays on its front page a "message" .
- The "message" is decided by the owner of pre-defined NFTs (NFT_A and NFT_B)
- During odd days, the "message" of NFT_A owner is displayed; (NFT_B
  for even days)
- "message" should be stored on cardano database and be easily
  retrievable from the NFT id

To achieve that, I am considering the following :

- "message" will be store as metadata in TX; (the "message" displayed should be the metada on the latest TX)
- The message will be retrived by using a blockfrost.io api call

Do you think this is the right approach ? do you have any remark ?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you will query blockfrost each time someone lands on the website or once per day?

In case you start running into quota you could also run your own cardano-graphql instance to query metadata for asset (token) or you can use already hosted solution by gimbalabs https://gimbalabs.com/dandelion/graphql-api

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I thought about querying blockfrost one per day, and do a static redering of the website.
I am not so familiar with graphql but I thought it would be simpler to just go for an pre build solution ^^